# Jquery Collapsible panel - post back issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need some modification in the script but could not do it as i am not so friendly with jquery

When the page postback i want to maintain the state of the panels. Right now if i refresh the page all the panels are collapsed,

i am using the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(“DIV.ContainerPanel > DIV.collapsePanelHeader > DIV.ArrowExpand”).toggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().next(“div.Content”).show(“slow”);
        $(this).attr(“class”, “ArrowClose”);
    },function() {
        $(this).parent().next(“div.Content”).hide(“slow”);
        $(this).attr(“class”, “ArrowExpand”);
    });
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

What you asking for, is to remember the currently open panel.

Since this panel is not a native asp.net control, asp.net will not remember that value across postbacks.

One solution is to keep a hidden input control in your container and maintain the value of the currently open div in that input.

Asp.net would then receive and send back this data even on a postback.

On document ready you could then reopen the open panel by reading this value.

**Edit:** added some code

From your selectors, I assume your html looks like this.

```
<div class="ContainerPanel">
    <div class="collapsePanelHeader">
        <div class="ArrowExpand"">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content1" class="Content"">

    </div>
    <div class="collapsePanelHeader">
        <div class="ArrowExpand"">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content2" class="Content"">

    </div>
    <input id="selectPanel1" runat="server" class="selectPanel"/>
</div>
```

I have added an id for each content block. If you do not have ids, you would have to add them for this code to work.

Note the input tag at the bottom of the ContainerPanel. This will be required to remember which div was open. asp.net requires unique id tags for every element.

```
<input id="selectPanel1" runat="server" class="selectPanel"/>
```

And the js would be like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.ContainerPanel > div.collapsePanelHeader > div.ArrowExpand").toggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().next("div.Content").show("slow");
        $(this).attr("class", "ArrowClose");
        //Put the id of the selected content into an input
        //This is so that it goes to the server
        var inputBox = $(this).parent().parent().find(".selectPanel");
        inputBox.val("#" + $(this).parent().next("div.Content").attr("id"));
    },function() {
        $(this).parent().next("div.Content").hide("slow");
        $(this).attr("class", "ArrowExpand");
    });
    //This supports multiple ContainerPanel divs.
    $("div.ContainerPanel").each(function(e){
        //retrive value of div open before postback and show it
        var selectedContentId = $(this).find(".selectPanel").val();
            if(selectedContentId != "")
            $(selectedContentId).show();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: There you go. Made some modifications to your structure and js code. The code is untested, so tell me how it goes.

Comment: This is the structure of the div .. now likewise i have 7 divs

Comment: <div id="Div6" class="ContainerPanel">
                        <div id="Div7" class="collapsePanelHeader">
                            <div id="Div8" class="HeaderContent">
                                Retirement Saving Account</div>
                            <div id="Div9" class="ArrowExpand">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div10" class="Content" style="display: none">
                        </div>
                    </div>

Comment: It already supports multiple ContainerPanel divs. So you should be good. Note the input tag at the bottom of the div. You will have to add that to all the divs

Comment: <div id="ContainerPanel" class="ContainerPanel">
                        <div id="header" class="collapsePanelHeader">
                            <div id="dvHeaderText" class="HeaderContent">
                                Education Savings Account</div>
                            <div id="dvArrow" class="ArrowExpand">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="dvContent" class="Content" style="display: none">

its not working

Comment: id would have to unique for all your content divs. each container panel would also need you to add an input tag like in my answer.

Comment: I followed what you instructed 
var inputBox = $(this).parent().parent().find(".ContainerPanel");
is not recording the id of the container panel it is always blank

Answer (score 0):

that answer will do exactly what you want ,  I don't know what you are creating , or the reason for post back - but you might find the best approach is to eliminate the post back , and handle it ajax jQuery , that will stop all the problems you are having and create a much faster and more user friendly experience .

I have no clue what you're doing or what security issues you may have , but look into ajax if that is an option ,   that is a whole lot of code just to remeber the page state

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last two days working on this challenge in my own code. I need to be able to expand or collapse nine different panels from either jQuery or Code behind or even from the expand/collapse icon, and keep postbacks to a minimum. I also need to capture each textbox, ddl, checkbox value as it is entered.

My solution was a web service that interacts with jQuery and manages structure in session. The code behind and jQuery code can then share the data with the web service.

One set of values I keep in the structure is a flag that tells me whether the panel is expanded or collapsed.

Although this may be overkill for your problem, the flexibility this solution is amazingly powerful. By defining big chunks of data as a single class structure, I can read and update just about anything in 1-3 lines of code.